# ORACLE VARRAY Select output

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, varray

I am having a problem with `VARRAY` in `ORACLE`:

When I try to select a varray type in a table, the output in SQL Developer shows

```
VARRAY_TYPE
__________________________________________________
USERNAME.VARRYA_TYPE('TYPE1','TYPE2','TYPE3')
```

Can anyone point me out the way to get rid of the "`USERNAME.VARRAY_TYPE()`" and extract the result to be just

```
VARRAY_TYPE
__________________________________________________
'TYPE1','TYPE2','TYPE3'
```

My varray and table example are given here for your references:

```
CREATE TYPE varray_TYPE AS VARRAY(3) OF CHAR(20)
/

CREATE TYPE table_TYPE AS OBJECT (

tableID         number (6),
varray_var      GENRE_TYPE  
)
/

CREATE TABLE table1 as table_type(
tableID PRIMARY KEY
)
/

AND MY SELECT QUERY IS:

SELECT VARRAY_VAR AS VARRY_TYPE 
FROM TABLE table1
/
```

---

THANKS IN ADVANCE!

Answer (score 3):

Disaggregate the results with `cross join` and `table()`, then reaggregate them with `listagg` to add custom formatting.

```
select
    tableID,
    listagg(trim(column_value), ',')
        within group (order by column_value) varray_type
from table1
cross join table(table1.varray_var)
group by tableID

TABLEID   VARRAY_TYPE
-------   -----------
1         TYPE1,TYPE2,TYPE3
```

I had to make a few minor changes to your syntax to get this to work:

```
CREATE TYPE varray_TYPE AS VARRAY(3) OF CHAR(20)
/

CREATE TYPE table_TYPE AS OBJECT (
tableID         number (6),
varray_var      varray_TYPE  
)
/

CREATE TABLE table1 of table_type(
tableID PRIMARY KEY
)
/

insert into table1 values(1, varray_type('TYPE1','TYPE2','TYPE3'));

SELECT VARRAY_VAR AS VARRY_TYPE 
FROM table1;
```